# How to build a query to get the max result of the addition of columns of two models using Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I'm struggling to build a query in Rails which returns me the max value of adding two columns of two different tables. I have two models, lets name them `Audio` and `Property`, where `Property` has the columns `"id, audio_id, starts_at, collection_name"`, and Audio has `"id and length"`. What I'd like to do is to build the following SQL query in Rails:

```
SELECT MAX(property.starts_at + audio.length) FROM audio
  INNER JOIN property WHERE property.audio_id = audio.id
  AND property.collection_name = 'some_name';
```

The associations are simply `belongs_to :audio` for Property and `has_many :properties` for Audio. I could build this retrieving every Property where collection_name is 'some_name', iterating through each of them, saving the max to a variable and returning the max value:

```
def full_length
  full_lengths = []
  Property.where(:collection_name => 'some_name').each do |p|
    full_lengths << p.audio.length + p.starts_at
  end
  full_lengths.max
end
```

But that don't look so good performancewise nor seems to be the Ruby/Rails way to do it. Is there any combination of ActiveRecord methods which would allow me to do this?

Comment: Given that you know that raw sql you want to run, is there any reason to not do it that way?  As per the API http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#finding-by-sql

Comment: I understand how the API would help me retrieve full records as objects. But I'm unsure how to use it to retrieve processed data from different records. For instance, running that SQL query as First.find_by_sql(<that sql from the question>) returns an empty => #<First > object. Or am I stupidly missing something here?

Comment: May I suggest you to use some real word example instead of First, Second, this_value, that_value. Too abstract to understand for me.

Comment: Okay, I'll edit it. It can only get easier to understand I guess

Comment: If I understood correctly, Property is something like fragments of an Audio? If so, wouldn't it be nature that "collection_name" attr is in audio instead of property/fragment?

Comment: It also seems strange that you don't limit Audio to a certain id, when Properties belong to Audio. You are comparing a property with something it doesn't have relationship. Any login behind that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer I was looking for. Turns out it could be done chaining joins, maximum and where:

> Property.where(:collection_name =>
>   'some_name').joins(:audio).maximum('starts_at + length')
>
> (0.2ms)  SELECT MAX(starts_at + length) AS max_id FROM "properties"
>   INNER JOIN "audios" ON "audios"."id" = "properties"."audio_id" WHERE
>   "properties"."collection_name" = 'some_name'
>
> => 6038